# What is the difference between BigInteger type in System.Numerics.dll and the BigInteger type in FSharp.Core.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

As I understand, .NET has two types System.Numerics.BigInteger , one defined in System.Numerics.dll, the other in FSharp.Core.dll . What's the difference? Why does F# bother to define its own BigInteger type?

Also, can one use the FSharp.Core type from C#?

Comment: Just a tip: From [Numerics.BigInteger Structure (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee620695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) **This type is provided for use only with the F# Runtime that targets .NET Framework 2.0**. If you are using .NET Framework 4, use the .NET Framework 4 type with the same name, [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you can use FSharp.Core.dll in C# http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/10/10-reasons-to-use-f-runtime-in-your-c.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620695.aspx):

> This type is provided for use only with the F# Core Library Versions
>   that targets .NET Framework 2.0. If you are using .NET Framework 4,
>   use the .NET Framework 4 type with the same name, [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).